# How can I get raw probabilities from Spark ML OneVsRest classifier?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I want to solve a multiclass classification problem using one vs rest (all). I found OneVsRest in Spark ML, which breaks down the multiclass problem to several binary classifications. I was hoping there's a way to get raw probabilities, but I can't seem to find it. In mllib, I can use clearThreshold() to make a binary classifier like logistic regression return raw probabilities, but I don't see that method available in in ML logistic regression. I do see rawPredictionCol() which return a param, but no documentation on how to use it. I am using the Java spark API, and trying to get this [example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaOneVsRestExample.java) to product raw probabilities. question 2: for some reason I'm generaly finding Spark documentation lacking in far too many cases .. what am I missing?

Update: trying to read the source code.. not a very productive exercise; i'm not a Scala programmer. Will update with findings.

Comment: Hi Kai, Any Update on this?